# giving top positions to li using variables in jquery

Tags: jquery

hello friends i want to set position to every `<li>` using jquery i have tried following code but its not working as i want

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var t = 10;
var j = 0;

function cycle(){

var l = $('ul#move li').length - 1;
alert(l);
 $('ul#move li:eq('+j+')').css('top',t + 'px');

 if(j == l)

 {
     j=0;
     t = 10;
 } 
 else
 {
 j++;
 t = t+10;
 }

cycle();
}
})
</script>
```

html

```
<ul id="move">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
<style>
ul#move
{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    border:solid;
    font-size:3em;
    height:300px;
}
ul#move li
{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

i want to set top positions to every `<li>` the gap shuld be 10 px in every `<li>`

Please help

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about using margins?

Comment: @user1302513 does it HAVE to be in JQuery? Taking out a couple of your CSS lines achieves what you want? Let me know I'll post an answer detailing the changes

Answer (score 1):

I have a very strong feeling you are trying to do this

```
var lis = $('ul#move li')
var l = lis.length - 1;
var j, t;
lis.each(function(index) {
   if(j ==1) {
      j = 0;
      t = 0;
   } else { 
      j++;
      t += 10;
   }
   $(this).css('top',t + 'px');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/yXK4m/)

#### However, If gap is the only problem. A simple CSS can do the trick

```
#move li { margin-top: 10px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/yXK4m/1/)

---

#### Update

Animate li can be done like this

```
var lis = $('ul#move li')
var step = 30;
lis.each(function(index) {
    $(this).animate({
        'top': (index*step)+ 'px'
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/yXK4m/2/)

Comment: thanks for help strax but its not working plz check your code

Comment: @user1302513, Why do you need jquery to do this?

Comment: actually i want to animate them .. like scroll up in loop using jquery this question is my first step to do this ..

Comment: @user1302513, animate as in first li 10px, second li 20px?

Comment: i think u r right strax actually m getting too much confused with code
basicaly i want to design scrolling text using jquery. but i failed again and again :(

Comment: can u make it scroll like marquee .. ?

Comment: @user1302513, Dont be offended but I am not here to code for you. I am here to __help you code__, so you can use setTimeout() function make such marquee effect. Or search for jquery sliders and scroller

Comment: @user1302513, If you run into some difficulties, you can ask us, we will be glad to help you. :) And my name is Starx not `strax`. :D